# Changing listview item's text color based on data

Tags: java

I am trying to load an array of items into a listview from MySQL. Based on the data, if 'no_sms_service' = 1 then I want to change only that item's background color. I have tried to override the view but it doesn't specifically change the item. It changes all of the items. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void loadReservations() {

    ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.waitingList);

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+dbURL+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbDatabase+"";
    String user = dbUser;
    String pass = dbPass;

    List<String> waitingList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT cust_name, reserve_Date, Seat_prefer, reserve_people, Notes, no_sms_service FROM seat_reserve WHERE reserve_Close=0 && DATE(reserve_Date) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY reserve_Date ASC");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        String result;
        while (rs.next()) {

            String myTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp(2).toString();

            DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
            Date date = inputFormat.parse(myTimestamp);

            DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            String outputString = outputFormat.format(date);


            result = "\n" +"Name:  " + rs.getString(1)
                    + "\n" + "Reservation Time:  " + outputString
                     + "\n" + "Preferred Area:  " + rs.getString(3)
                    + "\n" + "Guests:  " + rs.getString(4)
            + "\n" + "Notes:  " + rs.getString(5) + "\n";

            waitingList.add(result);

            noSMS = rs.getInt(6);

            arrayAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            waitingList) {

                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                            if (noSMS == 1)
                            {
                                text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            }
                            return view;
                        }
                    };

        }

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: You're constructing a new array adapter for each item you're adding to the list. This is not how `ArrayAdapter`s are meant to be used.

Comment: Okay, what do you suggest?

Comment: Writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple issues with the code you've provided.

Firstly, when the View is constructed using `getView`, it's not evaluating the contents of the `result` string you're passing in as data. Since `ResultSet` is a transient data container, you'll need a more permanent storage solution for the data you're extracting so it can be evaluated when the `ListView` needs to update. Create following class:

```
public class ListItemData {
    ListItemData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        name = rs.getString(1);
        reservationDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S").parse(rs.getTimestamp(2).toString());
        preferredArea = rs.getString(3);
        guests = rs.getString(4);
        notes = rs.getString(5);
        noSms = rs.getInt(6) == 1;
    }

    String name;
    Date reservationDate;
    String preferredArea;
    String guests;
    String notes;
    boolean noSms;
}
```

You're also creating a new ArrayAdapter for each element in the list. This is not how `ArrayAdapter`s are supposed to work! A `ListView` can have only *one* `ArrayAdapter`, and it's logic is run on every item in the list by it's `getView` method.

The following should be put somewhere *outside* of `loadReservations`, probably in `onCreate`:

```
// only initialize the waitingList once here, and repopulate it in loadReservations
List<ListItemData> waitingList = new ArrayList<ListItemData>();

// only create the arrayAdapter once
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListItemData>(getApplicationContext(),
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                   waitingList) {
                   @Override
                   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                       View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                       TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                       ListItemData data = getItem(position);

                       //TODO: now you have access to all the data!

                       if (data.noSms)
                       {
                           text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                       }

                       return view;
                   }
               };

lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Now that the initialization heavy lifting is done in `ListItemData`'s constructor, our `loadReservations` function can be greatly simplified:

```
public void loadReservations() {

    ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.waitingList);

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+dbURL+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbDatabase+"";
    String user = dbUser;
    String pass = dbPass;

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT cust_name, reserve_Date, Seat_prefer, reserve_people, Notes, no_sms_service FROM seat_reserve WHERE reserve_Close=0 && DATE(reserve_Date) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY reserve_Date ASC");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        // clear out the waitingList (instead of making a brand new one!)
        waitingList.clear();

        while (rs.next()) {
            ListItemData data = new ListItemData(rs);

            waitingList.add(data);
        }

        // this must be called to notify the list to recalculate it's view
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I haven't compiled this code, if you spot any issues, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks much for your time! The ListItemData class gives me a java.sql.SQLException for each rs.getString/Int. Also the return view that we placed in the onCreate method is giving me an error ("Required: ArrayAdapter <java.lang.String>, Found: ".....ListItemData")

Comment: Somewhere, you have a reference to an `ArrayAdapter<String>`, all of the references regarding this `ListView` needed to have `ArrayAdapter<ListItemData>`. As for the SQL exceptions, what is the actual message returned?

Comment: Great, I did have a dangling ArrayAdapter<String>. Fixed that. I created a separate java file named ListItemData and stuck that class code into it. rs.getString and rs.getInt are giving me the error : " Error:(29, 28) error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown "

Comment: It just means that you need to wrap the ResultSet queries in a `try`/`catch` block.